# How to setup node.js terminal to always show the current directory

Tags: node.js

So, can I setup the node.js terminal to pernament show me the current directory that I'm in, if yes how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is nodejs REPL which you can test it

```
[david@s2 ~]$ node
> process.cwd()
'/home/monitor'
> process.chdir('../');
undefined
> process.cwd();
'/home'
```